# Heroku Express + Postgres addon requires elevated privileges

Tags: postgresql, express, heroku, sequelize.js

> [2018-05-16 08:27:12.979] [ERROR] server - Pipe
>   postgres://xnmcmqfirrdzkg:638d94fcd7aa5178e1054f0ff604613826033d5e8845fb42614c17a3d386823a@ec2-107-21-126-193.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/d5l5g60nk6l27a
>   requires elevated privileges

I'm trying to deploy server Express + Sequelize + Postgres on Heroku.

```
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable]);
} 
else {
  config.logging = function (str) {
    log4js.getLogger("sequelize").info(str);
  }
  var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}
```

The data's credential is set at **default**. I tried searching on the internet but there is no one having the same problem with me.

Comment: Are you using the configurations that Heroku add to your service automatically? Generally they add something like "DB_URL" which is a single environment variable with the full connection string.

Comment: That error message contains your database credentials. They are forever compromised; please invalidate them _immediately_ and then generate new ones.

Comment: I can't generate a new credential.
This operation is not supported by Hobby tier databases.

I'm wondering maybe hobby-tier leads to my problem ?

Comment: Then back up your data, delete that database, create a new one, and load your data into it. Continuing to use the one you have is a _**really bad** idea_.

Comment: In the end, i knew the problem :(

I use port 5432 when heroku doesn't support.
After change it into port 80. Everything works fine.

Thanks for all answers. I will close this topic.

Answer (score 0):

I am. But I have not been able to figure it out yet. And the docs I have been provided are more than two years old.